# What's the error with this VB code?

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010, integer, media-player

I'm trying to make the label's time change every second to match the time of the media being played.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim remain As Int32 = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration - AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition

    Dim Minutes As String

    Dim Secs As String

    Dim ElapsedTime As String

    Minutes = (remain / 60).ToString("00")

    Secs = (remain Mod 60).ToString("00.00")

    ElapsedTime = Minutes & "." & Secs

    Label1.Text = ElapsedTime ' Display the remaining time for the .wav file in a label in mm:ss format

    TrackBar2.Value = ElapsedTime (Error with this line: Conversion from string "11.26.00" to type 'Integer' is not valid.)

End Sub
```

Do I change the strings to integers instead?

Comment: TrackBar2.Value = remain

Answer (score 0):

I think its a matter of the compiler not being able to implicitly convert the values, I would either change the format of the string or do something like this:

```
Dim totalTime as Integer = 0
For Each thing In ElapsedTime.Split(".")
     totalTime += CInt(thing) 'So, "11.26.00" will turn into 11 + 26 + 0 = 37 for totalTime
Next
```

That's just a simple outline, you can do any additional arithmetic as needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.value.aspx), a trackbar needs to have its value set to an *integer* somewhere between the minimum and maximum.

That will be `0` and `10` if you're using the default minimum and maximum, or something else if you've changed them (obviously).

You need to figure out how to change the time string (or time remaining integer, `remain`) into a value between that minimum and maximum, then set the value to that.

Since you have the duration and position, you can possibly use something like:

```
Dim pos as Int32 = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition
Dim tot as Int32 = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration
Dim tenthsToGo as Int32 = 10 * (tot - pos) / tot
' Now use tenthsToGo (or 10-tenthsToGo depending on direction) to set trackbar '
```

If you have set the maximum to be the duration (and left the minimum at zero) as seems to be indicated in a comment, then you can simply set the trackbar value to the current position (which varies from 0 to the maximum).

Comment: Well, I set the max value using this:

`Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click

        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = (OpenFileDialog1.FileName)


        Timer1.Interval = 1000

        Timer1.Start()

        TrackBar2.Maximum = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration

    End Sub`

Comment: @NathanielWashburn, if you're setting the max to the duration then you need only set the trackbar value to the current position (or duration less current position, depending on desired direction).

Comment: What do you mean set it to the current position?

EDIT: I changed it to `TrackBar2.Value = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.markerCount` but the trackbar still oesn't move and the label just says 11 the whole time.

Comment: Actually, it goes from 11 to 6 to 5 to 6 to 11. -.-

Comment: @NathanielWashburn, why are you using markercount? That has nothing to do with how far you are through the file.

Answer (score 0):

can you use this code to display time of media player when played and duration of song or video it play sory 4 bad english

```html
 TrackBar2.Maximum = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.duration
        Label3.Text = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPositionString
        TrackBar2.Value = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition
        Label4.Text = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.durationString
```